# Visual Studio Cordova Application ID

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I was using Intel XDK to create Hybrid Apps.
I used the Application id for PlayStore as gkg4.pro.obs

Now recently I switched to Visual Studio 2015 with Cordova, however, whenever I am trying this ID, i.e. gkg4.pro.obs, I am getting Exit Code 8 error while compiling.

if I am trying gkg.pro.obs i.e. without numerical in id, its working fine.

I can't change the ID as its already live app.

Any solution to this issue ? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Cordova limitation, Cordova requires package name must look like **com.company.Name**. Visual Studio uses Cordova CLI to build and package app and therefore Application Id not in format com.company.Name throws build error. Please note VS2013 CPT3.0 is Cordova 4.0.0

**Workaround:**
Android package name is checked in C:\Users\[username]\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\lib\create.js (part of Cordova) and you can modify the package name validation regex to use (!/^[a-zA-Z**0-9**]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)+$/.test(package_name)) in below method.

```
function validatePackageName(package_name) {
    //Make the package conform to Java package types
    //Enforce underscore limitation
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)+$/.test(package_name)) {
        return Q.reject('Package name must look like: com.company.Name');
    }

    //Class is a reserved word
    if(/\b[Cc]lass\b/.test(package_name)) {
        return Q.reject('class is a reserved word');
    }

    return Q.resolve();
}
```

After making the above changes, clean solution and rebuild the project.

Please note this is only temporary fix and installation of Cordova will overwrite this file.

Comment: If there is such limitation then how come Intel XDK is able to build it in other format ?

Comment: Visual Studio is using Cordova 4.0.0 and I think Intel XDK is using lower version of Cordova

Comment: The regex in validatePackageName seems overly restrictive. I'd file a bug/enhancement request with the Cordova project.

Comment: Thanks a ton, hope they will fix it asap.